# enlarging a field, impact on mysql database

Tags: mysql

I would like to enlarge a varchar column on several tables in my mysql 5.5 database from 15 to 20 characters.  Will the table be locked/unusable during the alter table query, similar to if I add/drop a column?

The tables in question have several million rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/alter-table.html) (Storage, Performance, and Concurrency Considerations section) says that a table should still be readable when being altered, but that writes will be deferred until the `ALTER TABLE` is done.  So it would block writes, but not reads.